# cannot import image on react.js component

Tags: reactjs, import

Having issue with import img into react component

My component path is **src/components/Intro/Intro.js** and image is in public/logo.png

This is my component: I can se

```
import React from 'react'
import './Intro.css'
import logo from './logo.png'

const Intro = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='img'> <img src={logo} alt="/" /> </div>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Intro
```

error: Module not found: Can't resolve './logo.png' 
I have tried ../public/logo.png, .../public/logo.png and loads other paths but nothing seems to work

[image]

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of your project structure?

Comment: Three dots wont work, does it? It needs to be ../../../public/logo.png or something.

Comment: Done @Skoltz :)

Comment: Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. this is the new fresh one haha im using create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder `assets` inside the src/ directory
2. Move your logo to this folder
3. Access it using `import logo from '../../assets/logo.png'`